# Display the selected dates after validation of the post symfony form

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, multidatepicker

I have a problem with jquery's multidatepciker, after selecting the dates and submitting the form, I want the dates to remain selected but it does not work
Here is my code :

Here is the form

```
{{ form_start(formReservation) }}   
            {{ form_row(formReservation.firstName, {'attr': {'class': 'input-form-contact'}}) }}
            {{ form_row(formReservation.lastName, {'attr': {'class': 'input-form-contact'}}) }}
            {{ form_row(formReservation.email, {'attr': {'class': 'input-form-contact'}}) }}
            {{ form_row(formReservation.phone, {'attr': {'class': 'input-form-contact'}}) }}
            
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between div-number-rods align-items-center checkout-rods">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-form-reservation me-2 decrease-btn"><i class="bi bi-dash-lg"></i></button>
                {{ form_row(formReservation.numberRods, (reservation.numberRods is not null ? {'attr': {'value': reservation.numberRods} } : {}) ) }}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-form-reservation ms-2 increase-btn"><i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i></button>
            </div>

            {{ form_row(formReservation.dateReservation, {'attr': {'class': 'input-form-contact picker'}}) }}

            <div class="picker mb-3 rounded"></div>

            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center border mb-3 card-total-price">
                <h5 class="price" data-price="20">20€ par canne à pêche / jour</h5>
                <h4 class="total fw-bold mb-0">Total: <span id="total">{% if reservation.price is not null %}{{ reservation.price }}{% else %}0{% endif %} €</span></h4>
                <h4 class="total fw-bold mb-0">Nombre de journée(s) : <span id="nbDays">{% if reservation.numberDays is not null %}{{ reservation.numberDays }}{% else %}0{% endif %}</span></h4>
                <input type="hidden" id="total-price" name="total-price">
                <input type="hidden" id="total-days" name="total-days" value="1">
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                <button type="submit" id="submit-form-contact" class="btn btn-dark btn-form-contact-message g-recaptcha" data-action='submit'>Valider</button>
            </div>
        {{ form_end(formReservation) }}
```

```
    $('.picker').multiDatesPicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            console.log(date);
            // console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
            // console.log(arrayDateSelect);

            // const multipleExist = arrayDateSelect.every(value => {
            //     console.log(value);
            //     return [true];
            // });

            // console.log(multipleExist);

            // if ($.inArray(date.toLocaleDateString(), arrayDateSelect) != -1) {
            //     console.log('ok date');
            //     return [true]; 
            // }

            day = date.getDay();            
            if ((day == 0 || day == 6)) {
                return [true];
            } else {
                return [false];
            }
        },
        onSelect: function(){
            // console.log($('.picker').multiDatesPicker('value'));
            
            $('#reservation_form_dateReservation').val($('.picker').multiDatesPicker('value'));
            var dateLenght = $('.picker').multiDatesPicker('getDates').length;
            var dateLenght = $('#total-days').val($('.picker').multiDatesPicker('getDates').length);

            var nbDays = $('#nbDays').text($('.picker').multiDatesPicker('getDates').length);
            // console.log(nbDays);

            var price = +$(".price").data("price");
            // console.log('price ' + price);

            var quantity = +parseInt($('#reservation_form_numberRods').val());
            // console.log('quantity ' + quantity);

            var numberDays = +$('#total-days').val();
            // console.log('numberDays ' + numberDays);

            $("#total").text((price * quantity) * numberDays + "€");
            $("#total-price").val((price * quantity) * numberDays);
            // $("#total").text((price * quantity) * numberDays + "€");
        },
    });
```

I noticed that the inline:block option does not work with mutlidatepicker, so I used a block div, everything is correctly mapped in the database, the only problem is keeping the selected values ​​after submitting the form. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try and use the *altField* from the docs [here](https://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/#demo-alt-field) and set the value{s) on that field. Create another hidden form field that populates the values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is already and it works in the database, the problem is that if I want to modify a reservation, I want the dates stored in the database to be selected on the datepicker

Comment: I solved the problem using addDates option of multidatepicker. THANKS